# @State Changes the whole SwiftUI ForEach loop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am facing a loop problem so basically what this does it loads the Image as "noIcon" firstly then when it fetches the zip file img data it changes the zip image photo but when I have multiple zip files in the download manager they keep writing over the others
Example:

```
1st Zip Download IMG = 1st Zip Download IMG
but when the 2nd Zip Download fetches its img
1st Zip Download IMG = 2nd Zip Download IMG
2nd Zip Download IMG = 2nd Zip Download IMG
```

```
struct DownloadViewPageOne {
    @State var PngData = UIImage(systemName: "noIcon")!
    @ObservedObject var downloadManager = DownloadManager.shared

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(downloadManager.tasks, id: \.self) { task in
            HStack{
                Image(uiImage: PngData)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .leading).cornerRadius(20)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.2))
                    .onAppear{
                        let operation = Operation()
                        operation.completionBlock = {
                            PngData = GetAppIconFromZipHTTP("\(task.currentRequest!.url!)")
                            
                        }
                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation(operation)
                    }
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("\(task.currentRequest!.url!)").lineLimit(1)
                    ProgressView(task.progress)
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal).padding(.vertical,5)
            
            if (task == downloadManager.tasks.last) { } else { Divider().padding(.horizontal)}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `AsyncImage`? You can just use that without misusing `State` and `ForEach`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `AsyncImage` does not cache your images.

Comment: `ForEach` is a `View` data struct not a loop and `id: \.self` is a mistake, check the docs for `ForEach`

Comment: You need an `@State` for each row